# Why there is not loading screen in VMWare?

Tags: screen, vmware

I have installed **Ubuntu 15.10** in **VMWare Workstation 12.0** as I cannot dedicate it to a machine.
Everything's OK so far, but one little thing:
the loading screen does not appear, and all commands executing at startup are seen.

Remember that screen with the **Ubuntu** logo and the orange dots indicating the OS is loading startup processes? It does not appear?
Other than that the OS is working properly.

Comment: That's verbose boot. I'm usually able to toggle that by pressing the up arrow key or the F8 button while it shows, but you might need to do something else. I'll do a little research.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1911846